# cannot figure out why stack works but not queue to check if a given word is a palindrome

Tags: c++, stack, queue, push, palindrome

I use stack and queue to check if a given word is a palindrome. The I can push a new character into stack but i cannot push more than one character into queue. I cannot see where is my mistake in the code. Any help will be appreciated. Below is the code in C++ using Dev-C++. Thanks for your time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void push_char()
{

  string givenword; int sizeword, countchar;
  string letter;
  stack<string> stackword; string stawo1;
  queue<string>  queueword; string quewo1;

  cout<<"enter the word to test "<<endl;
  getline(cin,givenword);
  string str (givenword);
  sizeword=str.size();
  cout<<" the word given   "<<givenword<<"   size of word= "<<sizeword  <<endl;
  countchar=0;
  bool pali=true;

  while ((countchar<sizeword))
  {          
    stackword.push(str.substr(countchar,1));
    queueword.push(str.substr(countchar,1));
    cout<<" stack letter= "<<stackword.top()<<" queue letter= "<<queueword.front()<<endl;
    countchar++;

    if(stackword.top()==queueword.front())
      cout<<"same letter found !"<<endl;
    else
      pali=false;

    if (pali==false)
      cout<<"not a palindrome"<<endl;
    else
      cout<<"palindrome!"<<endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  push_char();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your queue is only pushing the one letter? When you do queueword.front() you'll always get the same letter in the print out because a queue works as First in, First out. Change it to .back() and I bet you won't think you're getting an error.

Comment: I added indention to your code for clarity and I believe some of your code is inside the loop that shouldn't be.  Not sure what you intended  to write.

Comment: I try to display every time there is a new letter in the stack and the queue. From the display, the stack shows a different letter while the queue shows only the first letter.

Comment: I even tried the queueword.back() and I still get the same result. I still display only the first letter pushed in the queue but not the rest of letters pushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, you can use str[countchar] instead of str.substr(countchar,

a few points:

1) Your code is fine, your algorithm is not. Grab a piece of paper and step through what you're doing.

2) I see what you're trying to do... something like this following untested code, right?

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeword; ++i) {
  stackword.push(str[i]);
  queueword.push(str[i]);
}

pali = true;
for(int i=0; i<sizeword; ++i) {
  if(stackword.top() != queueword.front()) {
    pali = false;
    break;
  }
  stackword.pop();
  queueword.pop();
}
```

Comment: yes indeed. I would like to stop the loop whenever the current character in the stack is different from the one in the queue.

Comment: Trying the changes above, and i got "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Comment: make stackword and queueword stack<char> and queue<char>, not string.

Comment: good call, fileoffset. @T4000, note that I have two loops while you only have one--that's why you're code isn't working. You're filling the stack and queue and checking them in the same loop when you have to fill them with all letters first and THEN check them.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to find a palindrome... but that isn't the question you asked.

In this line:
if(stackword.top()==queueword.front())

Is where your error is. When you push into a queue, you push at the end of it. The front will not change. So to you it appears that there is only one thing in it.

When you push onto a stack, it pushes on top of the existing stack.

Comment: even queueword.back() is not giving me a different result. I still have the same output when i display the character just pushed into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options here. Number one is what aleph_null suggests - double pass where you add the characters into the containers in the first pass and compare them in the second pass. Second option is to compare them the way you do but looking at the opposite ends of the word. You don't actually need any containers for this but with the minimal changes your while loop the code should look like this:

```
while ((countchar<sizeword))
{          
  stackword.push(str.substr(countchar,1));
  queueword.push(str.substr(sizeword - 1 - countchar,1)); // adding from the back
  cout<<" stack letter= "<<stackword.top();
  cout<<" queue letter= "<<queueword.back()<<endl; // .back() not .front()
  countchar++;

  if(stackword.top()==queueword.back()) // again, looking at the last added char
    cout<<"same letter found !"<<endl;
  else
    pali=false;

  // as Joe McGrath pointed out this should probably be outside the loop...
  if (pali==false)
    cout<<"not a palindrome"<<endl;
  else
    cout<<"palindrome!"<<endl;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Roman